# Pytorch C++ API : CMake Issue

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch

I want to include the pytorch C++ API to the large C++ software I am working on.

For legacy reasons, I must use `find_package`  and the associated `find_path` and `find_library` functions, instead of the [proposed](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html) `target_link_libraries`.

Here's my FindTORCH.cmake :

```
include( FindPackageHandleStandardArgs )

find_path( TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR torch/torch.h
           PATHS 
           /path/to/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/
           NO_DEFAULT_PATH )

find_library( TORCH_LIBRARIES libtorch.so
              PATHS
              /path/to/libtorch/lib/
              NO_DEFAULT_PATH )


FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS( TORCH REQUIRED_VARS TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR TORCH_LIBRARIES )

if ( TORCH_FOUND )
message( STATUS "Torch found" )
endif( TORCH_FOUND )

mark_as_advanced( TORCH_LIBRARIES TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

At the compilation, the torch files are found and I can `include <torch/torch.h>` in a random .cxx in the project.

However, if I add to the .cxx :

```
torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
cout << tensor << std::endl;
```

Then I cannot compile anymore and I get the following error :

```
/path/to/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:4:10: fatal error: ATen/record_function.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ATen/record_function.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm working Ubuntu 18, C++ 14, and the cmake version is 3.10.2 .

Thanks in advance

Comment: `find_package` is the correct solution and is not deprecated by any means. It has to be used with `target_link_libraries`

Comment: what is the content of your `CMakeLists.txt`? Can you include the revelant parts that create your executable and link to Torch?

Answer (score 1):

Torch exposes its own targets. To use them effectively, simply *remove `FindTORCH.cmake`* from your project, and add `/path/to/libtorch/` to your prefix path:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19) # or whatever version you use
project(your-project CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/path/to/libtorch/")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED CONFIG) # this ensure it find the file provided by pytorch

add_executable(your-executable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(your-executable PUBLIC torch::Tensor)
```

---

If you really insist to use your own `FindTorch.cmake` instead of the correct one, you can modify it to create an imported target that you will then link:

You can change your find module very slightly to gain a modern CMake interface from it:

```
include( FindPackageHandleStandardArgs )

find_path( TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR torch/torch.h
           PATHS 
           /path/to/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/
           NO_DEFAULT_PATH )

find_library( TORCH_LIBRARIES libtorch.so
              PATHS
              /path/to/libtorch/lib/
              NO_DEFAULT_PATH )


FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS( TORCH REQUIRED_VARS TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR TORCH_LIBRARIES )

if ( TORCH_FOUND )
    message( STATUS "Torch found" )
    add_library(torch::Tensor SHARED IMPORTED) # mimic the names from pytorch maintainers
    set_target_properties(torch::Tensor 
    PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        # on windows, set IMPORTED_IMPLIB to the .lib
    )
endif( TORCH_FOUND )

mark_as_advanced( TORCH_LIBRARIES TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

Then, in your main CMake file, you can use the imported target like any other targets:

```
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(your-executable main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(your-executable PUBLIC torch::Tensor)
```